# Validar solo fechas despues del dia de hoy en javascript o php?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una duda, quiero saber como puedo validar una fecha despues del dia de hoy, por ejemplo, hacer una cita es necesario que sea despues del dia de hoy sin que deje seleccionar un dia antes al actual. Si alguien sabe seria de mucha ayuda, gracias. :)

Comment: pero validar de que lado? frontend? backend? tienes que validar esa característica en algún plugin?, trata por favor de mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: del lado del frontend, en el que el cliente no se le permita seleccionar dicha fecha, espero me haya explicado bien

Comment: el campo que dices es de tipo date?, es decir en tu formulario el input lo declaras como date?

Comment: si, el input lo declaro como date

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que antes que nada leas la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date) de los `input` de tipo `date` ya que te puede ser muy util para trabajar con este tipo de validaciones..

Sin embargo, para tu caso particular sería muy sencillo validarlo con el atributo `min` y un poco de ayuda de JavaScript

```js
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if(dd<10)
    dd='0'+dd
  if(mm<10)
    mm='0'+mm
    

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("fecha").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="date" id="fecha">
</form>
```

Comment: gracias compañero